# Eclipse and Hadoop 2.2 Location Status Updater Error

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 16 and have installed Eclipse (Kepler) and Hadoop 2.2.0. I have set Eclipse to use the Map/Reduce perspective and I have created a new Hadoop location. When I created the location, I went into the Advanced tab and set the path for:

- dfs.datanode.data.dir
- dfs.namenode.name.dir
- dfs.data.dir
- dfs.name.dir

When I click the + sign next to the location name, I get the following error:

> 'Map/Reduce location status updater' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during "Map/Reduce location status updater".

When I click on Details, I get the following:

> An internal error occurred during "Map/Reduce location status updater". java.land.NullPointerException

I have seen a few items on stackoverflow regarding Hadoop versions prior to 2.2 and they haven't solved this error for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which MapReduce plugin do you use? [One](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn) that I know has such a poor support that it will never work with new versions of Eclipse and Hadoop.

Comment: Did it work just after filling the fields in general tab, i.e. without modifying the fields on advanced tab?

Comment: @ViacheslavRodionov I am using the plugin which can be download from [here](https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin) with kepler and hadoop 2.2.0 . It is working as old ones.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin from Github, just as your link mentions. Thanks for that -- I should have mentioned the source. I also tried creating a new Hadoop location without changing any of the parameters on the advanced tab, but I got the same error.

I ran eclipse with the debug parameter and got the following:
`java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getAllJobs(JobClient.java:814) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.jobsToComplete(JobClient.java:790)`
It continues but I am running out of characters. Is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve just got the same problem!!

detail:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.core.jobs
Error
Wed Jul 02 18:46:23 CST 2014
An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getAllJobs(JobClient.java:814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.jobsToComplete(JobClient.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer$LocationStatusUpdater.run(HadoopServer.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```